# Magento - track onepage payment step

Tags: magento

I want to track the onepage payment step (Ajax response) by adding a JS tag before;

```
</body>
```

Have you any idea? Can the tag operate knowing that no page load is loaded?

Comment: The payment step is retrieved by AJAX already so there is no `<body>` tag then.

Comment: Do you mean to track the steps using Google Analytics for Goals/Conversions?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the right module for you:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/FOOMAN/extension/171/fooman-google-analytics-plus